# Resizing a UIImage View on Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode4

[image]So I've literally looked everywhere but can't see an easy example of how to resize a **UIImageView**! my current code is using an **IBAction** and a **UIView.animate** to move the image UP and into the corner, all I am trying to add to it, is to make it resize smaller to fit! ANY pointers would be amazing as I am new to swift :)

```
@IBAction func ContinueTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    print("pressed!")
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations:{
        self.aapTitle.frame.origin.y -= 150; self.aapTitle.frame.origin.x -= 50;})
```

Comment: can you share your code or screen shot.

Comment: ^ Just did, added the relevant area.

Comment: A few thoughts. (1) If you `@IBAction` is wired up to a `UIImageView`, remember to set `isUserInteractionEnabled = true`, as the default is false. (2) If you are using auto layout, do not change frames. (3) Have you tried removing the animation piece to see if something else is going on?

Comment: The animation MOVEMENT works fine... ill set the `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` as suggested, but I'm after a way to resize the image after/ as part of the animation??

Comment: if you are using Autolayout. create the outlet of top constraint of apptitle like.
@IBOutlet weak var topconstraint: NSLayoutConstraint! 
 in animation block add this line---  
      topconstraint.constant = 5

Comment: and if you are not using autolayout use this to change frame size in animation block.
self.aapTitle.frame = CGRect(x:15, y: 25, width: 35, height: 35)

Comment: That worked thanks Saxena

Answer (score 0):

the best way of doing it which was given to me via SAXENA was: `self.aapTitle.frame = CGRect(x:15, y: 25, width: 35, height: 35)`